# jquery touch carousel slider menu navigation

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

Trying to add public methods to this slider I purchased but have little knowledge implementing public methods. Test page can be seen here: http://oddopolis.com/2012/index_test.html
I would like the menu items on the right (work, interiors, info) when clicked, would move the slider to a  specific slide when hit. Info for instance would move the slider to the very last image on the slider.

Slider documentation can be found here:
http://www.dev.solvingtheweb.com/touchcarousel/documentation/documentation.html

I know I have to give IDs/Class to the items but have no knowledge on how to.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, right now you've got multiple div's with the same ID's.

After you fix that, you can just add a click event listener on the image and use the goTo function that your carousel provides like so:

```
$("#Image73").click(function() {
    var carousel = $("#carousel-gallery").data("touchCarousel");
    carousel.goTo(carousel.numItems); //Go to the last item
});
```

Comment: Changed the div ID's but don't know how to add a click event listener on the last image. Not sure if the script is correct on the page either. Thanks for the quick response.